# Blocking package installation

Tags: android, installation, package, block

Is it possible to block the installation of a  package on a Honeycomb device?
What I'd like to have is an application (or service or everything) that, once running, it inhibits subsequent installation of other packages.
Let's suppose to be a service. While it runs, if the device user attempts an installation by the Market, it will be aborted.
It is possible (continue supposing) to register an `APPLICATION_IS_ABOUT_TO_BE_INSTALLED` broadcast receiver that can break the `PackageManager` process?

Thanks in advance
L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nopes ! AFAIK, Not possible yet !

Comment: I would be surprised if they allow this for normal apps. May be they can add this functionality to the device admin APIs, but still I doubt

Comment: my boss will not be happy (but I do). Many thanks to advantej